# Python saving results to variables

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to loop through an array and I am checking where I have connection. (from an other function comes back a 0 or 1)

The bold arrays should be my results. I want to save them to a global variable, myResults, but if I print it at the end, then I will get back a much longer array...

I think the global variable is overwritten, why does it happen?

Thank you :)

**[[['A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'A3'], 26]
[[['A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'A4'], 'A3'], 32]**

[[[['A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4'], 'A3'], 26], [[['A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'D3', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4', 'C4', 'D4'], 'A3'], 32]]

```
def callbackFunction(start, end, time):
    myResult = []

    def logToVariable(path, goal, timeFor):
        finalPath = path
        finalPath.append(goal)
        print(finalPath)
        add_result = [finalPath, timeFor]
        print(add_result)
        myResult.append(add_result)

    def innerLoop(start, end, time):

        correctList = [item for item in myList if item not in start]
        for i in correctList:

            first = start[-1]
            time_diff = directPoints(first, i, time)

            if time_diff[1] == 1:
                if i==end:
                    #new_result = []
                    new_result =  [[start, i], time_diff[0]]
                    #logToVariable(start, i, time_diff[0])
                    # print(start, i)
                    myResult.append(new_result)
                    print(new_result)
                    #break
                    #return result
                else:
                    start.append(i)
                    innerLoop(start, end, time_diff[0])
            else:
                continue
    innerLoop(start, end, time)
    print(myResult)
    return myResult
```

Comment: There are no globals in this code at all. You instead have functions nested within another function, and you're using the containing function's scope kind of like a global scope except just for the functions within `callbackFunction`. That may or may not be related to your issue but I wanted to point out the incorrect/confused terminology.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed - it is called `print debuging` - maybe your code doesn't add elements to this variable or it adds too much elements and you get "much longer array...".